# osx - boost and python undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: python, c++, xcode, boost, symbols

I'm using C++11 and python 2.7.8 with Boost 1.55.0. I'm compiling with a universal architecture and OS X 10.9 SDK. I am compiling libRocket python bindings and it requires boost and python. I have installed both and generated the .xcodeproj from CMake. However upon compiling I received this error and cannot for the life of me figure it out. I've tried downloading and installing 32/64bit library's for boost and python, but nothing changes. I also checked with lipo -info and the library's contain both i386 and x86_64 architecture.

error msg:
http://pastebin.com/DnVqSy9P

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the python framework was corrupted. For future reference when dealing with these problems, these are the steps I recommend you take.

1) Check all installs. Make sure their not corrupted and in the correct location.

2) Make sure their LINKED to the project. You can tell if its not linked because the clang error will start with **ld:** and have the word **linker** in it.

3) Make sure the librarys/frameworks your using are compiled for **both 32bit and 64bit** architecture.

4) Make sure if you compile the library/framework from scratch you compile for **universal** architecture.

5) Make sure **"Build Active Architectures Only"** is set to **no!**

6) Make sure that ***your*** project is building for either **32bit or 64bit!** and your computer's architecture is the correct one for your project!